# getredirecturl not appending http

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using to get the targeturl using

```
httpSessionRequestCache.getRequest(request, response).getRedirectUrl();
```

it's only returning localhost:8080 because of this the redirection is not happening

I am expecting this should return as

```
http://localhost:8080
```

Any suggestions?